# Using Explorer View in Sharepoint 2010 - works sometimes

Tags: explorer-view

Some users are having issues using the Expolorer View.  At first they may get the you don't have permission to do this message, but sometime if they try 3 or 4 times, poof it will then work.

I tried it using a test ID with the same permissions on the site as the user.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me, and help me getting it to work on the first try?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: how many servers do you have in the farm?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Resolutions:

1)   Make sure the Office client should be installed on the machine.

2)   Make sure the web client service in started mode, How to check this: On your machine- Start-Run-services.msc-start the webclient service.

3)   Make sure the IE (Internet Explorer) Version should be 32-bit and not a 64-bit. How to check this: http://www.tracker-software.com/knowledgebase/280-How-do-I-tell-if-I-am-using-a-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-IE

4)   Make sure the client integration is Enabled in Central Administration
How to check this: Central Administration-Manage web applications-Ribbon-Authentication Providers-Client Integration check box.

5)   Make sure the STSSYNC add-on should be enabled in IE. How to check this: Open IE-Tools-Manage Add-Ons-Look for the STSSYNC add-on and enable it.

6)   Make sure this option “Enable additional actions and Online Status for members” in Central Administration is set to Yes. How to check this: Open the Central Administration page-Click on Manage web applications-Select the web application you would like to configure-From the ribbon select General Settings-In the section titled Person Name Actions and Presence Settings change the setting Enable additional actions and Online Status for members to Yes-Click OK to apply changes.

7)   Make sure the ActiveX Control is enabled in Internet Explorer. How to check this- Open IE-Tools-Manage Add-Ons-Look for the STSUpld UploadCtl Class add-on and enable it.

8)   Make sure the Internet Explorer settings should not be too high. How to check this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/change-internet-explorer-security-settings

9)   Make sure the protected mode should not be enabled in Internet Explorer. How to check this: Open internet explorer- Click on Tools menu and select Internet Options- Select Security Tab in the Internet options windows- Select Internet from the zone settings- Uncheck Enable Protected Mode option to disable the protection from Security for this zone- Hit Apply and Ok.

10)               Make sure the SharePoint site should be added inside trusted sites zone. How to do this: http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.in/2010/07/site-prompts-for-credentials.html
- See more at: http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/open-with-explorer-is-disabled.html#.VJLrqzGsWxU

I found the answer [here](http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/open-with-explorer-is-disabled.html#.VJLrqzGsWxU).